# Is there a way of decrypting an encrypted text using t-sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I encrypt a text using 1024 bit RSA encryption with the public key on the application.

What I want to do is to call a stored procedure with the parameter `@encryptedText` which will return the decrypted text (private key is in SQL Server but I don't want to send the private key to the application)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is usually better architecture to do all processing in code and just use SQL for data storage and retrieval.

Comment: I don't know if this helps in your specific situation, but instead of using TSQL you could use a CLR stored procedure so you can use .NET on the server side.

Comment: In SQL server I have used in the past sha1 hashing algorithms. In case you just want to validate this could be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150646/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022807-1.aspx#postadlink
It seems they handle rsa encryption from within SQL server.
Hope that helps!

Comment: RSA encryption can be handled by creating ASYMMETRIC KEY in the SQL. However, what I want to do is to decrypt a text encrypted autside of the sql with another RSA-Key(A key that is not created in the SQL as ASYMMETRIC KEY)

Comment: What about using SQLCLR? You could use .net encryption/decryption functions from within SQL Server.